# multiple members in New-DistributionGroup not working

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a new distribution group from one CSV using the following code.

```
 Import-Csv -Path C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\CIS\script\csv.csv | ForEach { New-DistributionGroup -Name $_.name -Members $_.members }
```

and my CSV has the following data.

```
name            members
ITDepartment    divyesh@xyz.com,milan.ramani@xyz.com
```

but when I run the above command it always gives me the below error.

```
Couldn't find object "divyesh@xyz.com,milan.ramani@xyz.com". Please make sure that it was spelled correctly or specify a different object.
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-DistributionGroup], ManagementObjectNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=AM6PR08MB4279,RequestId=4dc85b89-0791-4a2b-9409-beaf728789aa,TimeStamp=19-09-2022 14:31:12] [FailureCategory=Cmdlet-ManagementObjectNotFoundEx 
ception] 10D55A27,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.NewDistributionGroup
+ PSComputerName        : outlook.office365.com
```

I don't where am I doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ranadip Dutta's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73775347/15339544) provides the context as to why the code is failing, the `-Members` parameter from the [`New-DistributionGroup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/new-distributiongroup?view=exchange-ps) cmdlet accepts multiple values (**array of values**) when adding multiple members, however, what you have in your CSV is a **single string** having two members concatenated with a comma. You can however convert this comma delimited string into an array using the [`.Split` string method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-6.0):

```
Import-Csv -Path C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\CIS\script\csv.csv | ForEach-Object {
    New-DistributionGroup -Name $_.name -Members $_.members.Split(',')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are facing is a content issue in the CSV file. The two email IDs are although separated with comma but powershell is not able to parse it properly because it is considering both the emails IDs together as one single string.

Kindly work on handling that and try with a sample file with clean and structured content. It will push through.

I do not see any issue in the script line however if you are considering it to be a robust script for future then try having proper error handling, logs and other necessary things so that it would be easier for you to debug specific objects in future.

Comment: Yes, It is content issue...but, I don't know how to resolve it. I have tried Split, Join, String, String-Out and put variables in double-quotes. but not any success.

Comment: @DivyeshJesadiya: Since you have given the sample CSV in the question now, you have the solution also from Santiago :) That is why I was asking for the sample file.